# `ifelse` statement to return a number of columns based on matching strings

Tags: r

I have data on `earnings` which looks like the following;

```
# A tibble: 6 x 24
  m_ticker ticker comp_name    comp_name_2       exchange currency_code per_end_date_fr0
  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>             <chr>    <chr>         <date>          
1 AAPL     AAPL   APPLE INC    Apple Inc.        NSDQ     USD           2017-09-30      
2 AXP      AXP    AMER EXPRES~ American Express~ NYSE     USD           2017-12-31      
3 BA       BA     BOEING CO    The Boeing Compa~ NYSE     USD           2017-12-31      
4 CTR      CAT    CATERPILLAR~ Caterpillar Inc.  NYSE     USD           2017-12-31      
5 CSCO     CSCO   CISCO SYSTE~ Cisco Systems, I~ NSDQ     USD           2017-07-31      
6 SD       CVX    CHEVRON CORP Chevron Corporat~ NYSE     USD           2017-12-31      
# ... with 17 more variables: per_end_date_qr1 <date>, eps_mean_est_qr1 <dbl>,
#   street_mean_est_qr1 <dbl>, exp_rpt_date_qr1 <date>, exp_rpt_date_qr2 <date>,
#   exp_rpt_date_fr1 <date>, exp_rpt_date_fr2 <date>, late_last_flag <dbl>,
#   late_last_desc <chr>, source_flag <dbl>, source_desc <chr>, time_of_day_code <dbl>,
#   time_of_day_desc <chr>, per_end_date_qr0 <date>, eps_act_qr0 <dbl>,
#   per_end_date_qrm3 <date>, eps_act_qrm3 <dbl>
```

I also have a vector of `ticker` symbols called `tickers`.

```
tickers <- c("PYPL", "GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT", "CSCO")
```

I am trying to create an `ifelse` statement which will print a small table of the following columns from the `earnings` data:

```
ticker | comp_name | exp_rpt_date_qr1 | exp_rpt_date_qr2 | time_of_day_desc
```

So, if `ticker` matches `earnings$ticker` then print the above columns.

I have tried using `grepl` to print a basic `yes / no` which reports a warning message.

```
ifelse(grepl(tickers, earnings$ticker), "yes", "no")
```

Data:

```
earnings <- structure(list(m_ticker = c("AAPL", "AXP", "BA", "CTR", "CSCO", 
    "SD", "DIS", "GE", "GS&", "HOMD", "IBM", "ITL", "JNJ", "CHL", 
    "KO", "MCD", "MMM", "MRK", "MSFT", "NIKE", "PFE", "PG", "SPM", 
    "UNIH", "UA", "VISA", "BEL", "WMS", "J"), ticker = c("AAPL", 
    "AXP", "BA", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX", "DIS", "GE", "GS", "HD", "IBM", 
    "INTC", "JNJ", "JPM", "KO", "MCD", "MMM", "MRK", "MSFT", "NKE", 
    "PFE", "PG", "TRV", "UNH", "UTX", "V", "VZ", "WMT", "XOM"), comp_name = c("APPLE INC", 
    "AMER EXPRESS CO", "BOEING CO", "CATERPILLAR INC", "CISCO SYSTEMS", 
    "CHEVRON CORP", "DISNEY WALT", "GENL ELECTRIC", "GOLDMAN SACHS", 
    "HOME DEPOT", "INTL BUS MACH", "INTEL CORP", "JOHNSON & JOHNS", 
    "JPMORGAN CHASE", "COCA COLA CO", "MCDONALDS CORP", "3M CO", 
    "MERCK & CO INC", "MICROSOFT CORP", "NIKE INC-B", "PFIZER INC", 
    "PROCTER & GAMBL", "TRAVELERS COS", "UNITEDHEALTH GP", "UTD TECHS CORP", 
    "VISA INC-A", "VERIZON COMM", "WALMART INC", "EXXON MOBIL CRP"
    ), comp_name_2 = c("Apple Inc.", "American Express Company", 
    "The Boeing Company", "Caterpillar Inc.", "Cisco Systems, Inc.", 
    "Chevron Corporation", "The Walt Disney Company", "General Electric Company", 
    "The Goldman Sachs Group, Inc.", "The Home Depot, Inc.", "International Business Machines Corporation", 
    "Intel Corporation", "Johnson & Johnson", "JPMorgan Chase & Co.", 
    "Coca-Cola Company (The)", "McDonald's Corporation", "3M Company", 
    "Merck & Co., Inc.", "Microsoft Corporation", "NIKE, Inc.", "Pfizer Inc.", 
    "Procter & Gamble Company (The)", "The Travelers Companies, Inc.", 
    "UnitedHealth Group Incorporated", "United Technologies Corporation", 
    "Visa Inc.", "Verizon Communications Inc.", "Walmart Inc.", "Exxon Mobil Corporation"
    ), exchange = c("NSDQ", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NSDQ", "NYSE", 
    "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NSDQ", "NYSE", "NYSE", 
    "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NSDQ", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", 
    "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE", "NYSE"), currency_code = c("USD", 
    "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
    "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
    "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
    "USD"), per_end_date_fr0 = structure(c(17439, 17531, 17531, 17531, 
    17378, 17531, 17439, 17531, 17531, 17562, 17531, 17531, 17531, 
    17531, 17531, 17531, 17531, 17531, 17347, 17682, 17531, 17347, 
    17531, 17531, 17531, 17439, 17531, 17562, 17531), class = "Date"), 
        per_end_date_qr1 = structure(c(17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 
        17743, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17743, 17712, 17712, 17712, 
        17804, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17774, 17712, 17712, 
        17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17712, 17743, 17712), class = "Date"), 
        eps_mean_est_qr1 = c(2.19, 1.83, 3.43, 2.66, 0.63, 2.1, 2.04, 
        0.18, 4.67, 2.85, 3.03, 0.99, 2.06, 2.27, 0.6, 1.93, 2.59, 
        1.03, 1.07, 0.61, 0.75, 0.91, 2.44, 3.03, 1.86, 1.09, 1.15, 
        1.21, 1.24), street_mean_est_qr1 = c(2.187, 1.83, 3.434, 
        2.658, 0.689, 2.098, 2.043, 0.178, 4.674, 2.847, 3.031, 0.99, 
        2.055, 2.27, 0.601, 1.929, 2.594, 1.03, 1.074, 0.609, 0.748, 
        0.906, 2.436, 3.031, 1.858, 1.089, 1.145, 1.212, 1.244), 
        exp_rpt_date_qr1 = structure(c(17743, 17730, 17737, 17742, 
        17758, 17739, 17750, 17732, 17729, 17764, 17730, 17738, 17729, 
        17815, 17737, 17738, 17736, 17739, 17731, 17799, 17743, 17743, 
        17731, 17729, 17736, 17737, 17736, 17759, 17739), class = "Date"), 
        exp_rpt_date_qr2 = structure(c(17836, 17821, 17828, 17827, 
        17856, 17830, 17843, 17823, 17820, 17848, 17820, 17829, 17820, 
        17907, 17828, 17827, 17827, 17830, 17829, 17885, 17834, 17823, 
        17822, 17820, 17827, 17828, 17822, 17850, 17830), class = "Date"), 
        exp_rpt_date_fr1 = structure(c(17836, 17913, 17926, 17920, 
        17758, 17928, 17843, 17919, 17912, 17946, 17913, 17920, 17918, 
        17907, 17942, 17925, 17920, 17928, 17731, 18074, 17925, 17743, 
        17918, 17911, 17919, 17828, 17918, 17946, 17928), class = "Date"), 
        exp_rpt_date_fr2 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), late_last_flag = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), late_last_desc = c("Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", "Not late", 
        "Not late", "Not late", "Not late"), source_flag = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), source_desc = c("Company", "Company", 
        "Company", "Company", "Estimated", "Company", "Company", 
        "Company", "Company", "Estimated", "Company", "Company", 
        "Company", "Estimated", "Company", "Company", "Company", 
        "Company", "Company", "Estimated", "Company", "Company", 
        "Company", "Company", "Company", "Company", "Company", "Estimated", 
        "Company"), time_of_day_code = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 
        2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
        4, 2), time_of_day_desc = c("After market close", "After market close", 
        "Before the open", "Before the open", "Unknown", "Before the open", 
        "After market close", "Before the open", "Before the open", 
        "Unknown", "After market close", "After market close", "Before the open", 
        "Unknown", "Before the open", "Before the open", "Before the open", 
        "Before the open", "After market close", "Unknown", "Before the open", 
        "Before the open", "Before the open", "Before the open", 
        "Before the open", "After market close", "Before the open", 
        "Unknown", "Before the open"), per_end_date_qr0 = structure(c(17621, 
        17621, 17621, 17621, 17651, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17651, 
        17621, 17621, 17621, 17712, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 
        17682, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17651, 
        17621), class = "Date"), eps_act_qr0 = c(2.73, 1.86, 3.64, 
        2.82, 0.6, 1.9, 1.84, 0.16, 6.95, 2.08, 2.45, 0.87, 2.06, 
        2.29, 0.47, 1.79, 2.5, 1.05, 0.95, 0.69, 0.77, 1, 2.46, 3.04, 
        1.77, 1.11, 1.17, 1.14, 1.09), per_end_date_qrm3 = structure(c(17347, 
        17347, 17347, 17347, 17378, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17378, 
        17347, 17347, 17347, 17439, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 
        17409, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17347, 17378, 
        17347), class = "Date"), eps_act_qrm3 = c(1.67, 1.47, 2.55, 
        1.49, 0.55, 0.91, 1.58, 0.28, 3.95, 2.25, 2.97, 0.72, 1.83, 
        1.76, 0.59, 1.73, 2.58, 1.01, 0.98, 0.57, 0.67, 0.85, 1.92, 
        2.46, 1.85, 0.86, 0.96, 1.08, 0.78)), .Names = c("m_ticker", 
    "ticker", "comp_name", "comp_name_2", "exchange", "currency_code", 
    "per_end_date_fr0", "per_end_date_qr1", "eps_mean_est_qr1", "street_mean_est_qr1", 
    "exp_rpt_date_qr1", "exp_rpt_date_qr2", "exp_rpt_date_fr1", "exp_rpt_date_fr2", 
    "late_last_flag", "late_last_desc", "source_flag", "source_desc", 
    "time_of_day_code", "time_of_day_desc", "per_end_date_qr0", "eps_act_qr0", 
    "per_end_date_qrm3", "eps_act_qrm3"), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You need to use `"PYPL|GOOG|AAPL|MSFT|CSCO"` in the `grepl` statement where you have `tickers`.

Comment: The `tickers` vector will change depending on which `stock` I choose to analyse. It is not possible to pass a vector through `grepl`?

Comment: you can use `paste(tickers, collapse = "|")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `grepl` you can use `%in%`.
Furthermore, if all you're doing is choosing specific rows and columns to print, you could use `subset`.

```
> keepcols = c('ticker','comp_name','exp_rpt_date_qr1','exp_rpt_date_qr2','time_of_day_desc')
> subset(earnings, ticker %in% tickers, select = keepcols)
   ticker      comp_name exp_rpt_date_qr1 exp_rpt_date_qr2   time_of_day_desc
1    AAPL      APPLE INC       2018-07-31       2018-11-01 After market close
5    CSCO  CISCO SYSTEMS       2018-08-15       2018-11-21            Unknown
19   MSFT MICROSOFT CORP       2018-07-19       2018-10-25 After market close
```